# Как сделать index.php доступным по пути /?

Tags: php, apache

Сервер `Apache`, `PHP 7.4.20`.

Я хочу, чтобы при открытии страницы http://localhost/ открывался бы файл `index.php`. Сейчас мне приходится набирать http://localhost/index.php.

Как возможно произвести такой маппинг?